# MySQL after update, update datetime column of same table

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I have a table called `teamMembers`, this table stores a name and an e-mail address of a person:

```
id       INT (UNIQUE, AUTOINCREMENT)
name     VARCHAR(255)
email    VARCHAR(255)
updated  DATETIME
created  TIMESTAMP
```

I've created my trigger using `phpMyAdmin` and it looks like this in this export:

```
CREATE TRIGGER teamMembers.updated_updater 
AFTER UPDATE ON teamMembers
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE teamMembers SET updated = NOW() WHERE id = OLD.id;
        END
```

So when I use a query like this:
`UPDATE teamMembers SET name = 'test' WHERE id = 1`
I should set the updated column to the current datetime.

This is not working though, I get this error message:

> #1442 - Can't update table 'teamMembers' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

I cant really figure out what the problem is here. I think it's because this trigger would invoke itself as well and would therefore become an endless loop.
I think there must be a way to auto-update a record that has just been updated without altering my query.

Could someone help me to use a MySQL trigger to update to `updated` column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `before` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER teamMembers.updated_updater 
BEFORE UPDATE ON teamMembers
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET new.updated = NOW();
END
```

Comment: Why is this working with an `BEFORE UPDATE` and not for `AFTER UPDATE`

Comment: @FIA2008 . . . Because you cannot update the same table in a trigger.  However, you can *modify* the new data *before* it goes into the table.